# Trying to get 2 form fields next to each other (inline) using bootstrap 3 in MVC5 razor

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am trying to get WorkPhone and WorkPhone Extension side by side and aligned perfectly under the above field which spans the entire width of the column. This somewhat works but the extension field extends too far out to the right. The ideal scenario would be for it to look like this:

Work Phone
[textbox] ext [textbox]

**Here is what I have:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkPhone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WorkPhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkPhoneExt, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkPhoneExt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What other CSS do you have in the site? Is it only Bootstrap?

Comment: telerik kendo ui skin but I don't think it is affecting my bootstrap cols/rows /textboxes.

Comment: Have you tried pulling out the generated HTML and putting it into an isolated page with only Bootstrap included? You could use jsfiddle.net for this.

Comment: Also posting the generated HTML in the page may help, since this is a client-side issue but you only posted the server-side code in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this is a late reply and just ran across this post. Hopefully you have figured this out, I am posting the answer in case others need to use this.

In your `<div class="form-group">` you need to add the form-inline class as follows.`<div class="form-group form-inline">` and move this into the the row like this. 
`<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-12">
       <div class="form-group form-inline">`
Also need to remove the `<div class="col-md-8">` and `<div class="col-md-4">` sections so you can get them close together. 
Here is an Example:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkPhone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px" } }) 
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WorkPhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkPhoneExt, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" }) 
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkPhoneExt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:75px" } })
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I myself like to place the Labels above the boxes as the Text is smaller than the new `form-control` class and the text box is much bigger than the label text. I do this with the `col-md-12` class added to the label class .
Here is the code for that.

```html
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkPhone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WorkPhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkPhoneExt, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkPhoneExt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:75px" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WorkPhoneExt, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Hope this helps someone.